# Trying to get a list of groups that have permission to view a file in Google Drive

Tags: file, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Okay, so I'm writing a Google Apps Script for our intranet, and I want to be able to display a list of files from a folder on Google Drive. However, I only want to display files that the user has access to.

There is a method, `getViewers`, that will return a list of strings:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_file#getViewers

The problem with that is, although it returns email addresses for individuals who are on the permissions list, it returns **group names**. This is less than ideal, since there's no way to get the group object with [GroupsManager](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_groupsmanager#getGroup) -- it only takes the group ID.

There are a few things I could do in spite of this. One thing I tried was this:

```
var files = DocsList.getFolderById('0B_Zfq-SOMETHINGIJUSTMADEUP').getFiles();
for (f = 0; f < files.length; f++){
    var viewers = files[f].getViewers();
    var flag = false;
    // userGroups is the list of group objects, from this session's user
    for (i=0; i < usersGroups.length; i++){
        var groupName = userGroups[i].getName();
        if (viewers.indexOf(groupName) > -1){
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    if (flag){
        // print the link to file within the HTML template
    }
}
```

But that takes horribly long to load the page, for obvious reasons. It loads in like 5 minutes. What I really need is to be able to get a list of group email addresses from the `getViewers` method. It seems really strange that it returns emails for individual users, but group names for groups. Does anyone know any solution or workaround for this?

Comment: Incidentally, the deprecated Documents API that you could access via UrlFetch doesn't even list Groups in the ACL feed - so don't try that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet will probably be to use a [cache](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices#cacheService) with the groupIds mapped to group name and then use that instead of the GroupManager service otherwise it will be an age every time the script runs. Depending on how 'live' the docs list is for the Intranet site, you could speed things up also using a cache for the directory map.

If the permissions of files and directory listing are VERY changeable then the cache could be pre-populated by a helper script running on a [time-based-trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_triggerbuilder#timeBased) to suit your needs.

This is a good suggestion to add on the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) as a Feature Request.